# Druid setup ERROR: service serving this console is not responding

Tags: configuration, druid

I am trying to setup druid in cluster mode.
The setup is completer and there is no error in the server logs.
Even the druid console is launching successfully, but getting below error:

"**It appears that the service serving this console is not responding. The console will not function at the moment.**"

[image]

As you can see the status Apache druid is running successfully. But else where I am getting error message "**Error: Request failed with status code 500**"

Can anyone help me to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved.

Need to add below config in all node and in all cluster folder **runtime.properties**

druid.host=<respective_server_ip>

Example: in all server nodes (master, data, query)

1. In master folder: coordinator-overlord

druid.host=<master_server_ip>

2. In data folder: historical, middleManager

druid.host=<data_server_ip>

3. In query folder: broker, router

druid.host=<data_server_ip>

Answer (score 0):

- Do not configure druid.host=localhost when deploying as cluster, it
  will use the in-process function
  InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName() to get the
  hostname, which is very convenient
- Comment out below line in Druid configuration

conf/druid/cluster/_common/common.runtime.properties
#druid.host=localhost

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the zookeeper service is running.
If zookeeper is not running, start it.
And restart the services on the master server.